# iText merge pdf error in Android

Tags: java, android, itext

The code works well in Java application. But I can't compile when I transfer to Android. Error message: "The type java.awt.geom.AffineTransform cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" at the line:

```
cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);//compile error at this line
```

Then I tried commenting out the above line...but what happened was, this time the merged pdf file was created in Android but there's nothing inside...only blank pages.

This is the code used. Any help is appreciated.(Tried also using both droidText and the normal iText jars separately...still no luck)

```
public void concatPDFs() {

          Document document = new Document();
            try {
                uploadedFile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                 uploadedFile.setText(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
                List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
                pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("/storage/extSdCard/1.pdf"));
                pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("/storage/extSdCard/2.pdf"));
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/storage/extSdCard/merge.pdf");
                uploadedFile.setText("Added Files");
                List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
                int totalPages = 0;
                Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

                // Create Readers for the pdfs.
                while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
                    InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
                    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
                    readers.add(pdfReader);
                    totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
                }
                // Create a writer for the outputstream
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
                uploadedFile.setText("PdfWriter");
                document.open();
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                        BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
                // data

                PdfImportedPage page;
                int currentPageNumber = 0;
                int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

                // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
                while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                    PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                    // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                    while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                        document.newPage();
                        pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                        currentPageNumber++;
                        page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                                pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                        cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                        uploadedFile.setText("getImportedPage");
                        // Code for pagination.
                        if (true) {
                            cb.beginText();
                            cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                            cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                    + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520,
                                    5, 0);
                            cb.endText();
                        }
                    }
                    pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                document.close();
                outputStream.close();
                uploadedFile.setText("Done Pdf");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (document.isOpen())
                    document.close();
                try {
                    if (outputStream != null)
                        outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no `java.awt.*` packages are supported by Android, the only package from awt included in Android is `java.awt.font`.

Reference:
[Android packages available](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the previous answer, but I want to add that user614454 is using the Java version of iText instead of the official Android port. The official Android port can be found here: http://itextsupport.com/download/android.html

In this official Android port all java.awt classes that are needed by iText are replaced with light-weight alternatives.

Note that I'm the original author of iText. I removed a reference to DroidText because that's an Android port of an iText version that shouldn't be used anymore: http://lowagie.com/itext2