# iText merge pdf error in Android, with latest libraries

Tags: java, android, itext

I have read this question :

[iText merge pdf error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309434/itext-merge-pdf-error-in-android)

Which basically explains my problem, but the solution proposed - upgrading to the latest Android version of iText doesn't solve the issue.

I am using itextgoogle-5.4.0.jar, but I still get the same compile error.

Obviously when I get the project working I'll be happily paying the license fee, but the merging of PDF's is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue and re-uploaded 5.4.0 to the repository:
http://repo.itextsupport.com//android_gae/com/itextpdf/itextgoogle/5.4.0/

Could you confirm the fix?

Comment: Hi, yes the code is compiling with the latest version. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some compilation bugs in the iText port 5.4.0, it still has references to some of the java.awt classes. You'll notice this when you start using PdfContentByte.

I rolled back to the previous version 5.3.5 which is here :

http://repo.itextsupport.com//android_gae/com/itextpdf/itextgoogle/